# Usage of どうして in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

[image]

I'm a bit stumbled on how to take どうして　here? Is it a "why" or is the less common used meaning 3?

My reading is "no matter what, I won't love again"

Answer (score 1):

I would read this as,

> why [is it] only me [who ....]